# Channel equalization in uplink

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, equalization, fading-channel

I have a multiuser uplink signal $$ Y=h_1x_1+h_2x_2$$ where, $h_1$ and $h_2$ are channels for user 1 and user2 respectively. At the receiver how can I equalize the signal $Y$, assuming known $h_1$and $h_2$.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, it's not a homework question. I was working on a Power domain NOMA for two users in downlink. Now I want to do it for the uplink case. In downlink the equalization is simple, however, in uplink, I am confused about how to consider both h1 and h2 for equalization.

Comment: Could you add more details about what the difficulty is?

Comment: Like in downlink, we have y=(x1+x2)*h. So we equalize as y_eq=y./h=(x1+x2)h/h=x1+x2.  Now in uplink we have y=(x1h1+x2h2). Should I divide by h1,h2 or h1+h2. In any case I can't get back x1+x2.

Comment: Do you know anything about x1 and x2? Otherwise, you may need to estimate x1 with h2x2 as noise, and then estimate h2. Not an expert on this topic, but I think the CM algorithm is used for blind equalization as well; it has been adapted to the multiuser case as well.

Comment: You can't divide by h to equalize as that only works if the channel is minimum phase which can't be guaranteed (otherwise inverse channel has poles outside the unit circle: unstable). @AlexTP posted an answer that appears to be the correct approach to me (the least squares solution) but deleted it so I'm curious what he found wrong? Alex can you comment?  I assume the weight for each user is included in the known h1 and h2 given the OP's first formula.